# Change color of background and title in MFC Control

Tags: winapi, mfc

I want to change text color and background color for my EDIT CONTROL, STATIC CONTROL and BUTTON CONTROL in MFC application. The control is in a `CDialogEx` dialogue .

I try to add the OnCtlColor (with wizard in visual studio, on the WM_CTLCOLR message) but I can't set the color of may static control and button control.

I put also a break point in the `OnCtlColor` function (in the IF construct), but I don't receive anything.

I also tried to use the `SetTextColor` function retrieving the handle of the control from `GetDlgItem`, but I can't change the color as I want.

Pleas help me.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried.

Comment: By default all static controls have an ID of IDC_STATIC. Any static control that you want to manipulate must have a unique ID, not the default ID. In the resource editor change the ID of every static control you want to change into something unique for each control.

Answer (score 3):

I can assert that I tried to use in `OnCtlColor` in a `CDialog` and it worked for the static and for the edit controls.

All you have to do is:

- For changing background color, you need to create a brush that still exists outside that function and return its `HBRUSH` with

  `return (HBRUSH) m_brush.GetSafeHandle();`

  So you have to make a variable (`m_brush` in this code) that is member or a static (I recommend the first), and in the dialog initialization you have to create the brush you want.

  I thought maybe some controls will not work with this, and for those I also did

  `pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0,0,255));`

  But seems to do nothing; it is in the code for safety.
- For changing the text color,I did

  `pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255,0,0));`

These experiences worked well for edits and statics, but did not work at all for groupboxes!

Groupboxes are a strange entity in MFC, some kind of a platyplus: they are a `CButton` with the `BS_GROUPBOX`, but in this function, its `nCtlColor` is `CTLCOLOR_STATIC` instead of `CTLCOLOR_BTN`! I did this for them

```
UINT nStyle = (UINT)(pWnd->GetStyle() & 0x0F);

if(nStyle == BS_GROUPBOX)
{
    return (HBRUSH) m_brush2.GetSafeHandle();
}
```

and what got painted was the little rectangle behind the groupbox title!

I could not get the text colour of groupboxes changed!

If you have groupboxes and it is really important to change their titles' text color, you can get the one from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29016/XGroupBox-an-MFC-groupbox-control-to-display-text and get its essential code parts: to be derived from `CStatic`, the `OnPaint()` and `DrawItem()` methods. Do not forget also the `ON_WM_PAINT()` on the message map. I don't know if the `OnEraseBkgnd()` and its is `ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()` message mapping are so essential.
It is also needed to change them to be Static text controls in the resources, declare a `XGroupBox` variable and do a DDX_`Control` of it.
I tested it and it really works.

For buttons, with CButtons it did not work. But, for each button, I simply declared a   `CMFCButton` variable in the class and did a `DDX_Control` of each one. After, I had two choices:

- Set its `m_bTransparent` property to `TRUE` in the form constructor (search this variable on afxbutton.cpp file for reference) for the ones I wanted to have the same color as the form (I also painted the form; in my case I was implementing themes on an application)
- Set the Background color with `SetFaceColor()` and set the Text Color with `SetTextColor()` in form initialization.

When the `CMFCButton` does not have these things set, it got its color from theme blending of the currently selected `CMFCVisualManager`.

Note: I also replaced my `CSpinButton` entities with `CMFCSpinButon` ones, because I wanted colors from the selected theme.

In the `OnCtlColor`, the `nCtlColor` variable is important because it will allow you to personalize different colors to different types, without testing `dynamic_cast` success or failure for every control.

Do not forget to add `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()` to your message map.

**UPDATE 1:**
After following the advice of the accepted answer on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/53f47162-078a-418f-8067-ee61a81ceeac/checkbox-transparent-color-not-working-in-vs2008?forum=vcgeneral , I did my own Groupbox class, and now it is like:

```
class CMyGroupBox: public CButton
{
protected:
    virtual void PreSubclassWindow()
    {
        SetWindowTheme(*this, _T(""), _T(""));
        #pragma comment(lib, "UxTheme.lib")
    }
};
```

I just declared one of this, and did `DDX_Control` with its respective control ID, and now I can see the text in the color I supplied to `SetTextColor`. If you return a HBRUSH for this control, what gets painted is a non-filled rectangle drawn around the groupbox's title.

**UPDATE 2:** I just generalized the `CMyGroupBox` to be `CMyButton`, for using its `PreSubClassWindow` method not only in groupboxes, but also in checkboxes and buttons. In checkboxes it works well, in buttons, I am not so satisfied with the results.

**UPDATE 3:** I was trying to remove some weird effect on the rendering of the text and I just commented the `pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0,0,255));` line; the result was an ugly while rectangle behind the text :( . Then I replaced it with `pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);` and I also see tht weird effect :(

**UPDATE 4:** In order to avoid to have to declare all my checkboxes, groupboxes and buttons as the class that contains the PreSubClassWindow method, I researched and discovered that it is not needed to do it. The code

```
SetThemeAppProperties(0);
#pragma comment(lib, "UxTheme.lib")
AfxGetMainWnd()->SendMessage(WM_THEMECHANGED, 0U, 0L);
```

disables theming for all controls at the whole application level.