# paint background in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

I am experimenting with painting the background of a window in c++ using the MFC library. It is mandated that i use this framework because I am working on an MFC application. I have tried several different methods but cannot get it to work. So i recently opened a blank project and just want to figure out how to paint the background but it is not working. Any help would be great. Here is my code...

```
class CExerciseApp : public CWinApp
{   
     //a pointer to our window class object
     Basic_Window *bwnd; 

     BOOL InitInstance()
     {  
         bwnd = new Basic_Window();
         m_pMainWnd = bwnd;
         bwnd->ShowWindow(1);

         HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();

         CRect drawing_area;
         GetClientRect(hWnd, &drawing_area);

         CBrush newBrush;
         newBrush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));

         CDC* dc = bwnd->GetDC();
         dc->FillRect(&drawing_area, &newBrush);
         bwnd->RedrawWindow();
         return TRUE;
    }    
};
```

Comment: See WM_ERASEBKGND https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Should I post the WM_ERASEBKGND message before calling FillRect?

Comment: You don't post/send `WM_ERASEBKGND`, the system will do it when appropriate. You should rather override [CWnd::OnEraseBkgnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0a52fkz.aspx) and do your background painting there. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: What is a Basic_Window?  That is not an MFC window.  You need to put all your painting code like the FillRect() into the paint procedure of your Basic_Window, not just paint it in InitInstance, which is only called once.  It isn't working because as soon as another window (yours or another application's) covers it and then uncovers it, your painting does not occur again and is therefore gone.

Comment: But if a painting operation is done in InitInstance, shouldn

Comment: But if a painting operation is done in InitInstance, shouldnt it execute at least once? It is not, even when I insert breakpoints and view my window at the return of InitInstance

Comment: @Nathaniel:  I don't think you ever call the Create() method of bwnd.  So no HWND is created.  Therefore, I don't think GetActiveWindow returns the HWND of bwnd.  So you are painting an unknown HWND.  Does that HWND have the WS_VISIBLE style set?  Use Spy++ to see.  What are the coordinates of drawing_area?  You also don't have to call RedrawWindow.

Comment: To my understanding, the keyword new should be dynamically creating a new instance of bwnd. And the fact that my window appears when I call Show confirms that the bwnd is a valid pointer. The coordinates of the drawing area at the FillRect call are top=0,bottom=583,left=0,right=1060...So if the coordinates are a valid rect, the brush is created correctly, and I'm calling FillRect through the device context, passing in that brush and rect, I cant understand why nothing happens in my window

Comment: Does Basic_Window derive from CWnd?  If so, no, just doing a 'new' of it does not create its HWND, you have to either call the Create() or CreateEx() method.  What do you mean that 'your window appears'?  Where does it appear?  You don't give it any coordinates, so how does it know where to appear?  The reason "nothing happens" is that maybe your white rectangle is indeed painted, but then you call RedrawWindow which then erases it right again.  You really do need to put all your paint code within the window, and not in InitInstance.

Comment: This will never work because as soon as `InitInstance` returns, `Basic_Window`'s default handler for `WM_ERASEBKGND` will overwrite the background. I suggest you create a sample app and then replace the `CFrameWnd` derived class with your `Basic_Window`.

Answer (score 1):

From my own post https://stackoverflow.com/a/22875542/383779 , I can guarantee I had made that work. I used that approach for implementing themes/skins on a commercial application.

You need to add a OnCtlColor method to your Basic_Window class.
In your .h file, add to the Basic_Window class:

```
const CBrush m_BackgroundBrush;
```

and

```
afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor( CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
```

In .cpp file the constructor will initialize the new variable

```
Basic_Window::Basic_Window()
: m_BackgroundBrush(RGB(255,255,255))
{
//...
}
```

and implement

```
HBRUSH Basic_Window::OnCtlColor( CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if(some_exception)
        return __super::OnCtlColor( pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    return (HBRUSH) m_BackgroundBrush.GetSafeHandle();
}
```

`some_exception` here means a situation where you will want the default behavior, instead of your own painting. Maybe it is a certain type of control, and for that exists the `nCtlColor` parameter.

Do not forget to add `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()` to your message map.